# Pig programs just get stuck at a stage for no reason

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I am working on a data of size 400 MB , The script has 5 different section and has 5 store commands, If I switch only one store command at a time commenting all others, the pig scripts works awesomely.
But if all the 5 store commands are on, the job browser (hue) get stuck at no specific stage, and then it just keep reattempting a job with no progress. 
There is no error, and the logs also has no error nor warning.

The problem I recognize can be due to environmental issues as the script also worked fine with the -M attribute once but failed the other time.

Answer (score 0):

If each STORE data is dependent on previous STORE, then you can use exec command after each STORE. This will ensure that your STORE commands are executed completely before the next set of commands / STORE.

```
A = ...
STORE A;
exec;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the resource allocation policy use by yarn.
When you disk is full, it causes your node to become unhealthy which reduces the memory. 
Currently yarn scheduler (Fair Scheduler) just assign the total available memory equally to all the available jobs and there is no check for deadlocks which do occurs in my case.
The solution is change the scheduling by yarn, using capacity scheduling.